# PHP display image on same page from DB with jQuery Ajax or iFrame?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have used separate solve.php because headers should be set before any echo statements.

[program structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfWT9.jpg)

**Requirement:** To view image on the same page when click view.

**What I did:** I coded already jQuery ajax method to do that. But the image is not shown. It just shows lengthy string on processor.php instead of image when ajax method is executed. I suspect that it is headers problem.

Even when I use jQuery ajax method, does not the new headers from solve.php are brought to processor.php? Cannot I use jQuery ajax method to achieve my requirement?

I already searched Google and SO. I found something about using a hidden iframe. But I do not know how to do that, where to put it how to set its src attrubute? Do I have to use it with together with jQuery? Please can sombody provide me that code segment and explain me in Simple English because I am a beginnner.

Or is there any other way to do my requirement?

My jQuery method, and PHP codes works correctly.

Comment: are you serious? why don't you post your code inside your question?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not sure which part of code should be put here because it is big. please tell me.

Comment: the minimum needed to understand your problem and for being able to help you. that's just enough. if you want to know more about asking questions at stackoverflow, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask